# Why does enemy movement drag my rifle?

Tags: battlefield-4

I'm having a hard time figuring out why the movement of an enemy solider drags my rifle with him when I'm scoped?

Comment: Are you playing on console?

Answer (score 13):

It's a feature called **Aim Assist**.

It is designed to make aiming slightly easier, especially for console users, by "snapping" to an enemy should they cross the centre of your reticle.

It can be disabled in the game options.